# Transition-Time-Function Issue Code not working?

Tags: html, css

The output I'm getting is the box should move from left to right as per the code but it is not doing so.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  left: calc(100%-100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) requires spaces in the calculation so it needs to be `calc(100% - 100px)` to work. _"The + and - operators must be surrounded by whitespace."_

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `calc(100%-100px)` it should be `calc(100% - 100px)` inside of the `.parent:hover .child { }`, and as long as you hover over the parent element you should make the box move from left to right.

Comment: I already stated that in a comment 45 minutes ago. Please don't answer questions that are clearly at fault from a typo. Instead, vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo. This specific reason exists just for this purpose. Thanks

Comment: @j08691 OP has 19 reputation; they can't vote to close yet (they likely also aren't familiar with flagging). As a CSS and HTML gold badge holder, you should have been able to close this as a duplicate, no?

Comment: @TylerH Just educating a new user on closing and flagging. I voted to close as a typo, not a dupe.